# Empty parameter in remote launch

Tags: ros, urdf, parameter, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am launching my configuration in my robot from my desktop computer.

Everything work fine except loading an urdf file into a parameter. This is my launch file:

```
<launch>

  <machine name="auriga" address="192.168.1.103" user="auriga" default="true"/>
  <machine name="local"  address="localhost" />
 
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find auriga_model)/auriga_robot_box.urdf" />
  <param name="wii/axis_linear"   value="1"    type="int"/>
  <param name="wii/axis_angular"  value="0"    type="int"/>
  <param name="wii/scale_linear"  value="0.1"  type="double"/>
  <param name="wii/scale_angular" value="-0.1" type="double"/>
  <param name="wii/min_angular"   value="0.1"  type="double"/>
  <param name="wii/min_linear"    value="0.1"  type="double"/>

  <node  name="laser_hokuyo"          pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" machine="auriga" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <param name="calibrate_time"      type="bool"       value="false" />            <!-- Starts up faster, but timestamps will be inaccurate. -->
    <param name="port"                type="string"     value="/dev/ttyACM0" />     <!-- Set the port to connect to here -->
    <param name="intensity"           type="bool"       value="false" />
    <param name="min_ang"             type="double"     value="-2.08621" />
    <param name="max_ang"             type="double"     value="+2.08621" />
  </node>

  <node  name="wii_mote_server"       pkg="wiimote"               type="wiimote_node.py"            machine="auriga" respawn="true" output="screen"/>
  <node  name="auriga_robot_base"     pkg="auriga_base"           type="auriga_base_node"           machine="auriga" />
  <node  name="laser_broadcaster"     pkg="tf"                    type="static_transform_publisher" machine="auriga" args="0 0 0.73 0 0 0 base_link laser 50" />
  <node  name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"            machine="auriga" />
  <node  name="wii_controller"        pkg="auriga_teleop"         type="teleop_wii_node"            machine="auriga" />

  <node  name="visualization"         pkg="rviz"                  type="rviz"                       machine="local"  />

</launch>
```

The "auriga_robot_box.urdf" file exists in both computers in the same location but when I launch the system, the process "state_publisher" dies because the "robot_description" parameter is empty.

This configuration works fine when I run it all on a local machine.
What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9710/empty-parameter-in-remote-launch/) by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-04-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure what you are doing wrong, your launch file looks correct on first glance. Just as an idea for debugging, you can check if the parameter `robot_description` is set by running

```
rosparam get robot_description
```

from the command line. Can you do that from both `localhost` and `auriga`? Also, make sure that your [network setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) is correct (most importantly, ROS_MASTER_URI on `auriga` is set to the public IP of the machine that is running the roscore).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsogorb](https://answers.ros.org/users/372/jsogorb/) on 2011-04-17**:
Thank you, the problem was that the environment parameter ROS_MASTER_URI was not properly set. After adding this line to my launch file everything worked fine: